# Reciproc relationship migration order in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I am trying to create a relationship in Laravel Migration:

```
User > has many > Images
User > has one > Image (image_id) <-- Avatar

Image > belongsTo > User (user_id)
```

If I will create the migration with `references` to mark the relationships, the migration will fail because image needs User, and User needs image.

How should I order migrations to prevent this from happening?

(https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `users` and `images` tables in any order and add [foreign key constrains](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) in the second migration after creating the table. Or even in a separate migration file.

To add constrains use `table()` method instead of `create()`:

```
Schema::table('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Comment: I can do that? I am not imagining how to do another migration for same table

Comment: @PHPLover yes, you can. I've added an example to my answer, please check.

Comment: Thanks for the example :)